# Where can I edit the content of this field that contains the checkboxes of the mailing lists?

Tags: fields, field-mapping

I'm a novice with civi. Please, where can I edit the content of this field that contains the checkboxes of the mailing lists? I need delete one, but I don't find where I can edit the field content.
[image: see image of the field on frontend] ||| [image: see image of the field on backend]

Regards!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard for me to tell 100% for sure since I can't translate the text, but it looks like you're looking for custom fields.

Once you go in there, you should be able to find the field you're looking for.

[image: Custom Fields]